# Authlogic NameError - wrong constant name Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3

I am trying setup Authlogic gem with rails 7. I have simple controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    render_page 'Registration'
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(email: 'codcore@gmail.com', password: 415561)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render_page 'Registration', props: { errors: @user.errors_codes }
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation).to_h
  end
end
```

and simple `User` model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.inheritance_column = 'there_is_no_sti_here'

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.session_class = Session
    c.crypto_provider = ::Authlogic::CryptoProviders::BCrypt
  end
end
```

But when I call `create` action of `UsersController`, I get error:

```
NameError - wrong constant name 
      Object.const_get(camel_cased_word)
            ^^^^^^^^^^:
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

That error refers to `@user.save` in `UsersController`. I can not figure out what is happenning. I tried to debug this line, but did not understand what is going on. Also I tried `authlogic` gem right from the GitHub repository, but it didn't help.

The most interesing part that all works as intended when I create new instnce of `User` and then save it from `rails console`...

Comment: Is there any more to the stack trace than you've shared?
When you can save from the command line, are you passing the same arguments (email and password) to 'new'?

Comment: Just a hunch from reading some code; I think there's an issue with the `session_class`. I think that could be ending up here and trying to reference a constant that doesn't exist. https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/5e0253dcd91ea72c9a5acc5f62590142b7f4bdb4/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/session_maintenance.rb#L74

Comment: @JakeWorth thank you, I get rid of `session_class` call, and it worked!

Comment: I'd be happy to review a PR improving the error message here. Perhaps we could `rescue` the `NameError` and raise something better?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's failing [here](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/ef95d13b3f3ee846b54bc2510714f5e2fe84515a/lib/authlogic/session/base.rb#L765):

```
@klass ||= klass_name ? klass_name.constantize : nil
```

When it tries to get klass_name from session_class you've set:

```
# The model name, guessed from the session class name, e.g. "User",
# from "UserSession".
#
# TODO: This method can return nil. We should explore this. It seems
# likely to cause a NoMethodError later, so perhaps we should raise an
# error instead.
#
# @api private
def klass_name
  return @klass_name if instance_variable_defined?(:@klass_name)
  @klass_name = name.scan(/(.*)Session/)[0]&.first
end
```

In this case you should either configure `authenticate_with User` or rename `Session` to `UserSession` so it could get the correct name.